# jQuery for populating one datapicker value on other datePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to copy the date field(having Datepicker) value from one date field startDate into another field serviceDate on click of button using jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function init()
        {
    var startDate = $("#startDate_1").val();
    var servicesDate;
    $("#servicesDate").val(date1);
```

}

But its not working.Please suggest.

Comment: Google for chained select box One example http://blueicestudios.com/chained-select-boxes/

Comment: Please provide at least some code or evidence of effort. But you could do this using the jQuery DatePicker widgets `onSelect()` function [doc here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect). Just set the `.val()` of the second input to the value of the first.

Comment: Firstly, what is a data picker, is it some sort of plugin, or did you mean a datepicker, if so which datepicker. Also, try to explain the problem a little better, one sentence doesn't really say much

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks to do his work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for.

```
<input id="date1" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
<input id="date2" type="text" class="datepicker"/>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#date1").on("change", function(){
        $("#date2").val(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider two datepickers as:

```
$("#date1").datepicker();
$("#date2").datepicker();
```

Now you can copy one data picker field value to other data picker using jquery as:

```
var date1 = $("#date1").val();
$("#date2").val(date1);
```